# SharePoint permissions strange behavior

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a strange occurrence in People and Groups of our SharePoint 2013 Environment.

Users are there but the Names are blanked out but other information is there. Has anyone seen this happen before? I can hover over the check box and it will show a name.

[image]

Comment: have you verified the user profile sync service whether it is running correctly or not.

Comment: Profile sync is working from what I can tell, but I will verify this. We have multiple sites and none are having this issue except this new one.

Comment: user profile syn service proxy might be tied up with only this web app which is wrongly populating the details